# How to solve styling breaking on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have created a simple website using Next. It has a Navbar, and a few pages with nothing yet.
In my page.jsx, I import the landing page which I use as the Home page.
The navbar has links to the other pages.

When on the homepage, the styling is not breaking. Once I navigate to other pages, the styling is good but once I refresh any of those pages the styling breaks. When I navigate to home, everything comes on well.

###### Layout file

```js
 <html lang="en">
      <head> 
        ...
      </head>
      <WagmiConfig config={config}>
        <ConnectKitProvider mode="dark">
          <body>
            <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
              <Navbar />
              <div className="flex-grow">{children}</div>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          </body>
        </ConnectKitProvider>
      </WagmiConfig>
    </html>
```

[Normal site Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n3BC.png)

[When the site breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UwCN.png)

[My Repo](https://github.com/kihiuFrank/SaveAKid/tree/main/frontend)

I have tried searching for this from last weekend but can't find anything related. Your help is appreciated. The ones I have seen are using material UI but I'm not using it. I even changed the styling from normal css to tailwind css but the issue persists.